# How to convert a CSV with multiple sub-row items (from a column) to new columns in Awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

I have a CSV file with the general format shown in the picture below.

In that CSV there are multiple rows that belong to a certain column (`desc`) and I would like to to extract those items and add them to **new** columns called `name, size, weight, glass`, respectively. I have highlighted (in red) those sub-row items for the entries.

Original Structure:

[image]

Expected Structure:

[image]

---

The original CSV:

```
page,item,id,desc,price
1,2,F1,Alpha,111.11
1,,,380 x 2280 mm (size),
1,,,Weight: 33.0 kg,
1,,,Glass: AAA,
1,,,XXX,
1,3,F2,Beta,222.22
1,,,880 x 2280 mm (size),
1,,,Weight: 68.4 kg,
1,,,Glass: BBB,
1,,,YYY,
1,4,F3,Gamma,333.33
1,,,1980 x 1580 mm (size),
1,,,Weight: 78.2 kg,
1,,,Glass: CCC,
1,,,XXX,
1,,,YYY,
1,,,ZZZ,
```

Expected resulting CSV:

```
page,item,id,name,size,weight,glass,price
1,2,F1,Alpha,380 x 2280,33.0,AAA,111.11
1,3,F2,Beta,880 x 2280,68.4,BBB,222.22
1,4,F3,Gamma,1980 x 1580,78.2,CCC,333.33
```

where *name* would take the place of the first row in *desc*.

---

**UPDATE:**

Under certain conditions, some Awk solutions may work with the above, but fail when adding a 4th item. To fully test, consider adding this to the above:

```
1,7,F4,Delta,111.11
1,,,11 x 22 mm (size),
1,,,Weight: 33.0 kg,
1,,,Glass: DDD,
1,,,Random-1,
```

So 3 important points:

- The number of sub-rows in the `desc` column may vary.
- Any sub-rows after `Glass:...` should be ignored.
- There may be *items* that doesn't have any *sub-rows* in the `desc` column, they should also be ignored.

---

**Q: How can I remap those sub-rows into new columns, using *Awk***?
(Or are there more suitable tools for doing this in bash?)

Possibly related (but not very helpful) Questions:

- [how to concatenate columns with multiple rows using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402484/how-to-concatenate-columns-with-multiple-rows-using-awk)
- [How to split single column to multiple column in CSV file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453699/how-to-split-single-column-to-multiple-column-in-csv-file)
- [How to convert row to column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323636/how-to-convert-row-to-column)
- [Concatenating columns of the same csv file to create a new column with a new heading](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558347/concatenating-columns-of-the-same-csv-file-to-create-a-new-column-with-a-new-hea)

Comment: Can the `item` value ever be the number `0`?

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, no, but since the actual data is OCR extracted from a PDF file, there certainly could be garbage. I've tried to do some rudimentary pre-filtering using: `awk -F'[,"]' '($2~/[0-9]+/ && $3~/F[0-9]+/) || (!$2 && !$3)'`, because there may be rows that look like: *`sometimes,shit,happens,with,data`*.

Comment: `-F'[,"]'` is pretty suspect. Actually so are the other conditions. If you post a new question we can help you with that filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; print "page,item,id,name,size,weight,glass,price" }
    $2!=""{ price=$5; data=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; desc=""; c=0; next }
          { gsub(/ ?(mm \(size\)|Weight:|kg|Glass:) ?/, "") }
    ++c<=3{ desc=(desc==""?"":desc OFS) $4; next }
    data  { print data, desc, price; data="" }
' infile
```

---

including explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; print "page,item,id,name,size,weight,glass,price" }
     #this block will be executed only once before reading any line, and does: 
            #set FS (Field Separator), OFS (Output Field Separator) to a comma character
            #print the "header" line  ....

    $2!=""{ price=$5; data=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; desc=""; c=0; next }
    #this blocks will be executed only when column#2 value was not empty, and does:
            #backup column#5 into "price" variable
            #also backup columns#1~4 into "data" variable
            #reset the "desc" variable and also counter variable "c"
            #then read next line and skip processing the rest of the code 

          { gsub(/ ?(mm \(size\)|Weight:|kg|Glass:) ?/, "") }
            #this block runs for every line and replace strings above with empty string

    ++c<=3{ desc=(desc==""?"":desc OFS) $4; next }
    #this block runs at most 3reps and 
           #joining the descriptions in column#4 of every line
           #and read the next line until counter var "c" has value <=3 

     data { print data, desc, price; data="" }
     #if "data" variable has containing any data, then
           #print the data, desc, price and empty "data" variable 
' infile
```